# Is it possible to run an executable from a web service?

Tags: c#, web-services, exe

I have a web service and I would like to call an .exe file from within it.

Is this possible? If so, how is it done?

Comment: By WS do you mean Web Service or Web Site?  You'll need to provide a lot more detail here in order for people to give you a helpful answer

Comment: I think he wants his WebService to call an exe.

Answer (score 3):

I have done that is c# 3.5 with WCF. You can run a exe from a web service. The exe will run on the machine the service is host and with the user the service has been configured. You only have to write a normal [Process.Start(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) code.

So the answer is yes you can and, of course, the exe will run on the web service host and not the client. If you need more details, be more specific in your question.

Comment: Of course, you want your .exe to not have a UI or display to stdout, unless your service host has a UI or a stdout...