# How to run .exe file by my Webservice?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

> Duplicate:
>   [Is it possible to run an executable from a web service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717657/is-it-possible-to-run-an-executable-from-a-web-service)

Hi

I have Webservice, and I want to run exe file through this Webservice

the Webservice and the exe file are on same computer

How can I do it ?

thank's in advance

Answer (score 3):

Process.Start()?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the System.Diagnostics.Process object to start an external process.

**EDIT**:

[Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx)

[Example using some advanced features](http://blogs.msdn.com/lucian/archive/2008/12/29/system-diagnostics-process-redirect-standardinput-standardoutput-standarderror.aspx) (input/output/error redirecting). It's in VB, but should be easy to port.

Answer (score 1):

```
Process.Start("path of the program");
```

Comment: @ruud, run as admin, or make sure the user is allowed to execute the program.

Comment: what to run as admin?

Comment: I have windows 8.1. Is it allowed interaction windows service with the desktop?

Comment: Only if you explicitly allow it (check the "Allow service to interact with desktop" in the Log On tab of the service's properties)

Comment: I checked that option, but again its not opening.

Comment: `protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
            Process myProcess = new Process();

            try
            {

                myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe";
                myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                myProcess.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }


        }`

Comment: This is my code. Now I do not getting error, but it still not opening firefox. Is this option allowed on my system, windows 8.1?

Comment: @ruud no idea. But anyway, services run in their own session, so opening a app with an UI wouldn't show it to the user.

Answer (score 0):

```
Process.Start("app.exe")
```

OR even better, wrap it in a Windows Service, publish a schema for it and consume through async request to a bus.

Comment: Because you need to call: WaitForExit() on the Process instance, otherwise you don't get the result on the main thread.